Create a Dashboard View from a customer's list
I have a collection where I store customers with their info from multiple other collections.
I need to organize a document where the yearly info is separated by year, starting from 2020 until the current year (so next year, it will still works).
Then, for each year, I need to perform some checking to get the info/status for each array item.
If the customer checks true for the specific yearly Item, I have to add it's _id into a sub-array in the resulting query.
Here is a sample of my customers collection:
[
  {
    "_id": "308c9737-d216-485b-9172-372a554829b0",
    "OfficeId": "b6dcfe76-faf6-44e4-a40f-4eff74378f67",
    "Name": "Alicia Svetlana",
    "Emails": [
      {
        "Address": "alicia_sveta@gmail.com",
        "Title": "",
        "IsMain": true,
        "UseType": 0
      }
    ],
    "Status": 1,
    "Statements": [],
    "Budgets": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$binary": {
            "base64": "pkr1dgTWTmSvY7BSAOC1lw==",
            "subType": "04"
          }
        },
        "CalendarYear": {
          "_id": 2022
        },
        "BudgetStatus": 2,
        "PaymentStatus": 3
      }
    ],
    "Backlogs": [
      {
        "CalendarYear": {
          "_id": 2022
        },
        "ClosedAt": null
      },
      {
        "CalendarYear": {
          "_id": 2022
        },
        "ClosedAt": null
      },
      {
        "CalendarYear": {
          "_id": 2023
        },
        "ClosedAt": {
          "$date": "2024-03-31T02:40:38.304Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "CalendarYear": {
          "_id": 2023
        },
        "ClosedAt": null
      }
    ],
    "StatementDarfs": [],
    "CashYearlyInformations": [
      {
        "CalendarYear": {
          "_id": 2019
        },
        "CashBalance": 137512,
        "HasXml": true,
        "IsFinalized": false
      },
      {
        "CalendarYear": {
          "_id": 2020
        },
        "CashBalance": -2222,
        "HasXml": true,
        "IsFinalized": false
      },
      {
        "CalendarYear": {
          "_id": 2021
        },
        "CashBalance": -42682,
        "HasXml": true,
        "IsFinalized": false
      },
      {
        "CalendarYear": {
          "_id": 2022
        },
        "CashBalance": 0,
        "HasXml": true,
        "IsFinalized": false
      },
      {
        "CalendarYear": {
          "_id": 2023
        },
        "CashBalance": 13109,
        "HasXml": true,
        "IsFinalized": false
      },
      {
        "CalendarYear": {
          "_id": 2024
        },
        "CashBalance": -312845,
        "HasXml": true,
        "IsFinalized": false
      }
    ],
    "EcacStatus": []
  },
  {
    "_id": "2ecdd519-960b-4ac8-be72-9dbd72ae055c",
    "OfficeId": "b6dcfe76-faf6-44e4-a40f-4eff74378f67",
    "CustomerGroupId": null,
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "Emails": [],
    "Status": 1,
    "Statements": [],
    "Budgets": [],
    "Backlogs": [
      {
        "CalendarYear": {
          "_id": 2023
        },
        "ClosedAt": {
          "$date": "2024-04-15T15:03:21.647Z"
        }
      }
    ],
    "StatementDarfs": [],
    "CashYearlyInformations": [
      {
        "CalendarYear": {
          "_id": 2024
        },
        "CashBalance": 125772.6875,
        "HasXml": true,
        "IsFinalized": true
      }
    ]
  }
]

Some filters are not yearly, like Active, Inactive, WithEmail, WithoutEmail.
Others are yearly, like NegativeBalance(if CashBalance for that specific year is lower than zero, then I need to put the customer _id in the corresponding list if that item matches the condition.
Thing is, all yearly filter Specification must have all years in it's Specifications arrays.
And the result I need is something like this:
[
  {
    "_id": "b6dcfe76-faf6-44e4-a40f-4eff74378f67",
    "OfficeId": "b6dcfe76-faf6-44e4-a40f-4eff74378f67",
    "FilterGroups": [
      {
        "Name": "GeneralFilterGroup",
        "CalendarYearSupported": false,
        "Filters": [
          {
            "Name": "ActiveCustomer",
            "CalendarYear": {
              "_id": 0
            },            
            "Specifications": [
              {
                "CustomerIds" : [
                  "308c9737-d216-485b-9172-372a554829b0",
                  "2ecdd519-960b-4ac8-be72-9dbd72ae055c"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Name": "InactiveCustomer",
            "CalendarYear": {
              "_id": 0
            },            
            "Specifications": [
              {
                "CustomerIds" : [
                  "2ecdd519-960b-4ac8-be72-9dbd72ae055c"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },         
          {
            "Name": "WithEmail",
            "CalendarYear": {
              "_id": 0
            },
            "Specifications": [
              {
                "CustomerIds" : [
                  "308c9737-d216-485b-9172-372a554829b0"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "Name": "WithoutEmail",
            "CalendarYear": {
              "_id": 0
            },
            "Specifications": [
              {
                "CustomerIds" : [
                  "2ecdd519-960b-4ac8-be72-9dbd72ae055c"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }          
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "NegativeBalanceFilterGroup",
        "CalendarYearSupported": true,
        "Filters": [
          {
            "Name": "NegativeBalance",
            "Specifications": [
              {
                "CalendarYear": {
                  "_id": 2024
                },
                "CustomerIds" : [
                  "2ecdd519-960b-4ac8-be72-9dbd72ae055c"
                ]
              },
              {
                "CalendarYear": {
                  "_id": 2022
                },
                "CustomerIds" : [
                  "2ecdd519-960b-4ac8-be72-9dbd72ae055c"
                ]
              },
              {
                "CalendarYear": {
                  "_id": 2021
                },
                "CustomerIds" : [
                  "2ecdd519-960b-4ac8-be72-9dbd72ae055c"
                ]
              },
              {
                "CalendarYear": {
                  "_id": 2020
                },
                "CustomerIds" : [
                  "308c9737-d216-485b-9172-372a554829b0
                ]
              }                    
            ]
          }
        ]
      } 
    ]
  }
]

